# Configuring home network to connect TV cable box to ISP modem, through home network

Tags: networking, router

I have Gigabit service from AT&T with a direct fiber connection and a fairly complex network set up at home. Initially had all my devices connected to their router/modem (Arris BGW210-700) with my router (Asus RT-AC68Uv3 flashed Merlin). However I wanted to set up a VPN so I can connect remotely among other things and the Arris router just was not going to work for my needs.

So I changed it around so I set up IP passthrough from the modem to my router. This allows me to set up my router and service as I want and everything seems to be working well. Well, at least until I tried to watch TV (also through AT&T). The cable box regularly "loses connection" with the u-verse service. A channel will work for a few seconds after changing to it but will eventually "lose signal" after a few seconds.

[image: signal has been lost]

Ultimately, I think the cable box is trying to utilize a service on the modem ([connecting to a multicast stream](https://forums.att.com/t5/Watching-U-verse-TV/Persistent-Signal-Error-Uverse-Signal-has-been-lost/m-p/5186116/highlight/true#M28981)) and is failing to make the transition. Talking with the service techs, it's clear to me they don't know what to do, just that the cable box must be on the same network as the modem. Their only solution was to buy another AP just for the cable box to connect (wirelessly) to the modem or some variation of that. I don't want to do that, this sounds like it's just a network configuration issue.

Here's my general layout:

[image: network topology]

The modem and router is in a closet along with a NAS server. There's ethernet cabling from the closet to the other rooms. I eventually want to switch my "den" switch with a higher quality router/AP for better wifi coverage.

I feel there should be a way to configure in my router settings to have the cable box connect directly to the modem via a tunnel or something but I don't know how to articulate it or where I would apply changes. As far as I know, I can't set up a static IP address on the cable box, it's DHCP only. And I don't know how I would set up my router to allow the cable box through to the modem. Ideally the modem would allow bridging, but it doesn't which is why I used IP passthrough (cascaded routing is the only other option).

Will I be able to configure my network like I describe here? Is there a better, more optimal way to set this up? Or is my only option to get that dedicated AP just for the cable box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the option I was looking for was to enable multicast routing (IGMP proxy) as mentioned in the link above. In my router settings, that could be found in the IPTV tab of the LAN settings. Just didn't know where to look, thought it was a kind of port forwarding issue.

[image: IPTV]